# Downloading data from a web page (list) to an Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I have to download data from here:

[http://www.bcra.gov.ar/PublicacionesEstadisticas/Evolucion_moneda.asp][1]

Then I have to save all the data in an Excel. The problem is that I have to choose several dates and several currencies. For example, I have to select 12/31/2018, Dolar, Euro and Pesos. Moreover, I have to choose one currency at a time, and I have many to download. 
I've tried Import External Data with Excel, but it didn't work.

I've also tried with this VBA code

```
Sub descarga_monedas()

Fecha = "2018.06.05"
Moneda = 313

Path = "http://www.bcra.gob.ar/PublicacionesEstadisticas/Evolucion_moneda_3.asp?tipo=E&Fecha=" & Fecha & "&Moneda=" & Moneda & """"

Application.Workbooks.Open (Path)

End Sub
```

The page seems to block this kind of code.

Is any way to solve this?

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way. I have grabbed all the dates but included only one date to be used in conjunction with all currencies. Add another outer loop over dates to add in the dates values i.e. use an outer loop over inputDates collection to get each date.

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim  body As String, html As HTMLDocument, http As Object, i As Long
    Dim codes As Object, inputCurrency As Object, inputDates As Object, dates As Object
    Const BASE_URL As String = "http://www.bcra.gov.ar/PublicacionesEstadisticas/Evolucion_moneda_3.asp?tipo=E&"
    Set codes = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set inputDates = New Collection
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<== VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object library
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://www.bcra.gov.ar/PublicacionesEstadisticas/Evolucion_moneda.asp", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        Set inputCurrency = html.querySelectorAll("[name=Moneda] option[value]")
        Set dates = html.querySelectorAll("[name=Fecha] option[value]")
        For i = 0 To inputCurrency.Length - 1
            codes(inputCurrency.item(i).innerText) = inputCurrency.item(i).Value
        Next
        For i = 0 To dates.Length - 1
            inputDates.Add dates.item(i).Value
        Next

        Dim fecha As String, moneda As String, key As Variant, downloadURL As String
        Dim clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet

        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

        For Each key In codes.keys
            DoEvents
            fecha = inputDates.item(1) '<== use an outer loop over inputDates collection to get each date
            moneda = key
            downloadURL = BASE_URL & "Fecha=" & fecha & "&Moneda=" & moneda '2019.02.11 ,79

            .Open "GET", downloadURL, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = StrConv(http.responseBody, vbUnicode)

            clipboard.SetText html.querySelector("table").outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard

            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ws.NAME = fecha & "_" & moneda
            ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```